# How to show which users are viewing a screen in a asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2014

I have a web admin application running on asp.net / SQL Server 2014 / C#, and it has many different user screens, each user logs in to user the system etc, and uses a cookie to allow access.

How can I show a user which other users are already viewing the same screen?
What would be the best method?

Answer (score 3):

In a web app, as soon as the server delivers the HTML page to the client, there is no connection between the client and the server anymore. Of course you can easily track on the server which user requests a page. On the other hand there is no out-of-the-box mechanism that notifies the server if a user leaves the page.

However, you can create such a mechanism yourself using AJAX calls. Basically, you'd need to track which user requests a page and log this. On the page you'd add a script that notifies the server after regular intervals of time that the user is still watching the page. As soon as you do not get this notification anymore, you can assume that the user has left the page and remove the entry.

You could use the [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) framework to notify the other users of the page about changes so that the user list is updated on their client.

Comment: Yes, SignalR would be the better way.  Updates to client browsers would only occur when events (someone viewing the page) actually occur (avoids unnecessary updates and polling).

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look at that.